# Using star (*) in iPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

While working my way through Learning Python, this piece of code works fine in Spyder, but breaks in iPython:

```
# Create a sequence
sequence = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# Create two variables, the first with 'A', the second with the rest of the letters
Alpha, *allOtherLetters = sequence
```

When I try to run it in iPython, I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-b15e0241bc60>", line 5
    Alpha, *allOtherLetters = sequence
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Clearly iPython doesn't like the *, but I don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your IPython probably uses Python 2. `foo, *bar = ...` only works in Python 3. You can have a look at `sys.version_info.major` to check which Python version you are using.

Tee solution is to install IPython for Python 3. Since I don't know which distribution you use the easiest way might be creating a Python 3 venv and installing ipython in there using `pip install ipython`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Accidently activated py2 instead of py3.